# Android Emulator mdns

Tags: android, testing, emulation, mdns

I need to run tests on Android Emulator.
The app i need to test uses mdns to discover an device to talk to.
Is there any way, to connect the emulated android device directly to my network, so mdns works?

Thank you!

Walter

Comment: mdns may not work due other reasons (i.e. permissions or wifi.createMulticastLock) or...who knows why...I have the same issue.